# A veces crea las cardview y a veces no

Tags: android-studio

Una consulta. En mi código estoy creando una lista de CardViews a partir de un JSONArray que reccorro con un for y voy llenando una lista para crear las CardViews, solo que a veces si las crea y a veces no, no se por que, les dejo mi código.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promos_por_concepto);

    Intent promosIntent = getIntent();
    final Bundle promosExtras = promosIntent.getExtras();
    cp_id = promosExtras.getString("cp_id");
    listaPromosConcepto = new ArrayList<>();


    //Llamamos método para crear cards
    CreaCard();


}

public void CreaCard(){
    //Recibimos la respuesta del Json filtrada por el cp_id
    Response.Listener<String> promosConceptoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONArray promosArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int y = 0; y < promosArray.length(); y++) {

                    JSONObject promosObjectArray = promosArray.getJSONObject(y);
                    JSONArray promoConceptoArray = promosObjectArray.getJSONArray("promos");

                    for (int i = 0; i < promoConceptoArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject promoConcepto = promoConceptoArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String promoDesc = promoConcepto.getString("prom_desc");
                        String neg_Nomb = promoConcepto.getString("neg_nombre");
                        String calificacion = promoConcepto.getString("calificacion");
                        String promImgUrl = promoConcepto.getString("logo");
                        listaPromosConcepto.add(new FuentePromosPorConcepto("Título promo", neg_Nomb, promoDesc, promImgUrl, calificacion));

                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    };


    PromosInfoConceptoRequest promosInfoConceptoRequest = new PromosInfoConceptoRequest(cp_id, promosConceptoListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.add(promosInfoConceptoRequest);


    final RecyclerView recyclerPorConcepto = findViewById(R.id.recyclerContenedorDetalle);
    recyclerPorConcepto.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerPorConcepto.setAdapter(new PromosPorConceptoAdapter(listaPromosConcepto));
    recyclerPorConcepto.setLayoutManager(layout);
    PromosPorConceptoAdapter adapter = new PromosPorConceptoAdapter(listaPromosConcepto);
    recyclerPorConcepto.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: ¿ a veces si las crea? :-\ porque no agregas una imagen.

Comment: si, compilo y a veces si aparece la cardview y a veces no aparece. no entiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que creo que pasa es que estas haciendo una peticion con volley. Al ser tu peticion asincrona, no sabes en que momento tienes informacion en tu arreglo `listaPromosConcepto`. Algunas aveces cuando inicializas tu adapter, puede o no haber llegado la informacion que solicitaste con volley (por eso aveces muestra algo y aveces no)

Lo que tienes que hacer es despues de recibir los datos de tu peticion hacer un `notifyDataSetChanged` en tu adapter, para refrescar el contenido de tu lista.

```
private PromosPorConceptoAdapter adapter;


public void CreaCard(){
    adapter = new PromosPorConceptoAdapter(listaPromosConcepto);
    Response.Listener<String> promosConceptoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //etc etc rellenar arreglo
                //hacer esto fuera de los 2 ciclos for
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    };
```

Nota: estas asignandole 2 veces a tu recyclerPorConcepto el adapter, hazlo solo 1 vez.

Comment: Ya modifiqué el código como me comentas y sigue igual... No se que sucede.